# How to select from 3 tables having SUM as part of the query?

Tags: php, mysql

There are 3 tables.

1 - participante ==> table that holds people sign in to be part of a draw

2 - sorteado ==> table that holds the winners

3 - promocao ==> table that holds info from where people choose to sign in

When I make a draw, I would like to select the winners that are still not in the `sorteado` table (because I can have additional draws).
Also, I would like to select people with less points first, for example, people that havent been selected in previous draws)

What I have so far is:

```
select 
    sorteado.*, 
    participante.*, 
    (select sum(pontos) 
        from sorteado 
        where id_participante = participante.id_participante 
        and validade >= now() 
        group by participante.id_usuario) as s 
from sorteado 
right join participante 
on sorteado.id_participante = participante.id_participante 
where id_promocao = 49 
and sorteado.id_sorteado is null 
order by s, rand();
```

s would be the SUM. It shows NULL, but the correct value would be 3 (for id_usuario = 3).

If I change the query I get almost what I want. However, it works only if I pass the id_usuario = 3. However, I would like it to work on all users.

select sorteado.*, participante.*, (`select sum(pontos) from sorteado where id_usuario = 3 and validade >= now() group by participante.id_usuario`) as s from sorteado right join participante on sorteado.id_participante = participante.id_participante where id_promocao = 49 and sorteado.id_sorteado is null order by s, rand()

[image]

Bellow is the db dump

```
--
-- Table structure for table `participante`
--

CREATE TABLE `participante` (
  `id_participante` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `id_promocao` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_usuario` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `inscricao` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `participante`
--

INSERT INTO `participante` (`id_participante`, `id_promocao`, `id_usuario`, `inscricao`) VALUES
(43, 50, 3, '2019-02-08 09:06:31'),
(44, 49, 3, '2019-02-08 09:07:01'),
(45, 49, 6, '2019-02-08 09:07:01'),
(46, 49, 7, '2019-02-08 09:07:01'),
(47, 49, 8, '2019-02-08 09:07:01');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `promocao`
--

CREATE TABLE `promocao` (
  `id_promocao` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `descricao` text NOT NULL,
  `cota` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ingressos_ganhador` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pontos` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `prazo_pontos` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `encerramento` date NOT NULL,
  `mensagem` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `promocao`
--

INSERT INTO `promocao` (`id_promocao`, `nome`, `descricao`, `cota`, `ingressos_ganhador`, `pontos`, `prazo_pontos`, `encerramento`, `mensagem`) VALUES
(49, 'h2', '', 10, 1, 2, 30, '2019-09-14', ''),
(50, 'ppp', 'sdfsdf', 2, 2, 3, 10, '2019-02-07', ''),
(51, 'gfhjhgjgghjghjghj', '', 2, 2, 4, 10, '2019-02-07', '');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `sorteado`
--

CREATE TABLE `sorteado` (
  `id_sorteado` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_participante` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `data_sorteio` datetime NOT NULL,
  `pontos` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `validade` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `sorteado`
--

INSERT INTO `sorteado` (`id_sorteado`, `id_participante`, `data_sorteio`, `pontos`, `validade`) VALUES
(1, 43, '2019-02-08 00:00:00', 3, '2019-02-15 00:00:00');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `salt` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(254) NOT NULL,
  `activation_code` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `forgotten_password_code` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `forgotten_password_time` int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `remember_code` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_on` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `last_login` int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `company` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `users`
--

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `ip_address`, `username`, `password`, `salt`, `email`, `activation_code`, `forgotten_password_code`, `forgotten_password_time`, `remember_code`, `created_on`, `last_login`, `active`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `company`, `phone`) VALUES
(3, '127.0.0.1', 'xx@xx.xx.xx', 'xxx', NULL, 'xxxxx@xx.xx.xx', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'xxx', 1549028455, 1549626215, 1, 'renan', NULL, NULL, NULL),
(4, '', 'a', '', NULL, 'email a\r\n', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(5, '', 'b', '', NULL, 'email b\r\n', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(6, '', 'c', '', NULL, 'email c', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(7, '', 'd', '', NULL, 'email d', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(8, '', 'e', '', NULL, 'email e', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(9, '', 'f', '', NULL, 'email f', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `participante`
--
ALTER TABLE `participante`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_participante`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `unico` (`id_promocao`,`id_usuario`),
  ADD KEY `id_promocao` (`id_promocao`),
  ADD KEY `id_usuario` (`id_usuario`);

--
-- Indexes for table `promocao`
--
ALTER TABLE `promocao`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_promocao`);

--
-- Indexes for table `sorteado`
--
ALTER TABLE `sorteado`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_sorteado`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `id_participante` (`id_participante`);

--
-- Indexes for table `users`
--
ALTER TABLE `users`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `participante`
--
ALTER TABLE `participante`
  MODIFY `id_participante` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=48;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `promocao`
--
ALTER TABLE `promocao`
  MODIFY `id_promocao` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=52;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `sorteado`
--
ALTER TABLE `sorteado`
  MODIFY `id_sorteado` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=4;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `users`
--
ALTER TABLE `users`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=10;
--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `participante`
--
ALTER TABLE `participante`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_promocao` FOREIGN KEY (`id_promocao`) REFERENCES `promocao` (`id_promocao`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_usuario` FOREIGN KEY (`id_usuario`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`);

--
-- Constraints for table `sorteado`
--
ALTER TABLE `sorteado`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_participante` FOREIGN KEY (`id_participante`) REFERENCES `participante` (`id_participante`);
```

Comment: There is only one row in `sorteado` with `id_participante = 43`. So for 44 - 47 you get `NULL` as result. Why do you want it to be `2`?

Comment: id_participante is from a person with id_usuario = 3, that was select under id_promocao = 50. So, he would be the last option to be selected. I made a mistake on my question. Instead of 2, it should be 3. im editing the question.

Comment: I edited the dump too

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, I added another edit there, closest to the result I seek.